# How to distribute values within a certain range (0 - 1.0)

Tags: python, sum, distribution

In Python I have a dictionary of values with a sum of 1.0.

```
weights = {u'obj_1': 0.018564743024138134, u'obj_2': 0.012814665648003992, 
           u'obj_3': 0.38978992409415425, u'obj_4': 0.0594938403597285, 
           u'obj_5': 0.41613932145700294, u'obj_6': 0.10319750541697208}
```

I want to be able to set a new value to one of them, and the difference will distribute evenly to the rest of them. The sum of all values should always be 1.0.

I wrote this to do just that.

```
set_inf = "obj_4"
set_weight = 0.9

rest = set_weight-weights[set_inf]
distribute_count = len(weights)-1
distribute_weight = rest/distribute_count

for inf, val in weights.items():
    if inf == set_inf:
        weights[inf] = set_weight
    else:
        new_val = val-distribute_weight
        weights[inf] = new_val

    print "%s : %s" % (inf, weights[inf])
```

Which outputs:

```
obj_3 : 0.221688692166
obj_2 : -0.15528656628
obj_1 : -0.149536488904
obj_6 : -0.0649037265111
obj_5 : 0.248038089529
obj_4 : 0.9
Total sum: 1.0
```

obj_4 is set the value I want, and the sum is equal to 1.0. The problem is I want to make sure each value is never under 0, and never over 1.0.

That's where the confusion comes in, and I'm not sure the best way to handle it. If I limit the values, it needs to still compensate to other values otherwise the sum won't be 1.0. How can I achieve something like this?

`set_weight` can be any value between 0 to 1.0.

Comment: mathematically, this problem of yours has an infinite number of solutions. Assuming you set `obj_3`, the sum of all other objects must equal 1 - obj_3. There are infinite ways to do that even if you impose non-negative conditions to all of them. Long story sort, you need to come up with more conditions or leave things to chance.

Comment: I think I would want to distribute the difference based on percentage. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work the way I was expecting.

```
weights = [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1]

def update_value(index, new_value):
    dif = (1.0-new_value) / (1.0-weights[index])

    for i in range(len(weights)):
        if i == index:
            weights[i] = new_value
        else:
            weights[i] *= dif
```

This way it works if the new value is smaller or larger than the original value, and all other values propagate accordingly.

```
update_value(1, 0.6)
# Returns [0.13333333333333336, 0.6, 0.19999999999999998, 0.06666666666666668]
```

and

```
update_value(1, 0.1)
# Returns: [0.30000000000000004, 0.1, 0.44999999999999996, 0.15000000000000002]
```

If there's a better way please feel free to let me know!

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on the kind of algorithm you want to implement. If setting the values that become negative in your implementation to zero and distribute the rest of over the remaining ones would work for you, try something like this

```
def updateDict(oldDict, key, val):
    assert(val <= 1.0)
    assert(sum(oldDict.values()) == 1.0)
    while sum(oldDict.values()) + val > 1.0:
        nVals = len(oldDict)
        diff = 1. - (sum(oldDict.values()) + val)
        diffPerVal = diff / nVals
        for k in oldDict:
            if oldDict[k] + diffPerVal >= 0.:
                oldDict[k] += diffPerVal
            else:
                oldDict[k] = 0.
    oldDict[key] = val
```

Now

```
d = {1: 0.5, 2: 0.5}
updateDict(d, 3, 0.2)
```

yields `d = {1: 0.4, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.2}`, while

```
d = {1: 0.2, 2: 0.8}
updateDict(d, 3, 0.9)
```

yields `d = {1: 0.0, 2: 0.10000000000000009, 3: 0.9}`.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of something like this. Except I'm not appending new values, I'm just changing any of the existing ones. Trying to confirm this right, thank you!

Comment: this is what came first to my mind too, but you have to be careful. Dicts don't understand order so it can be that you try to update a value that would normally go below zero last. Who do you give the rest then? try running OPs example a number of times to see.

Comment: Oh, if  you want to only update an existing key/value, use the same function, calling `del oldDict[key]` after the asserts.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes I see what you mean! I forgot to mention that `set_val` can be any number from 0 to 1.0. The sum isn't usually 1.0 when using smaller numbers for it. This seems tougher than what I thought.

Comment: @GreenCell I am actually convinced that you have to change the container type, do your operations and then change back to `dict` when finished. A list of lists is what i would go for. like `temp = [[x,y] for x,y in weights.items() if x != inf]`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not quite sum up to 1 (I blame float accuracy), but I think you want to do it like this?

```
weights = {u'obj_1': 0.018564743024138134, u'obj_2': 0.012814665648003992,
           u'obj_3': 0.38978992409415425, u'obj_4': 0.0594938403597285,
           u'obj_5': 0.41613932145700294, u'obj_6': 0.10319750541697208}

set_inf = "obj_4"
set_weight = 0.9

rest = set_weight-weights[set_inf]
distribute_count = len(weights)-1
distribute_weight = rest/distribute_count

sum = 0.0
for inf, val in weights.items():
    if inf == set_inf:
        weights[inf] = set_weight
    else:
        weights[inf] = val*(1-set_weight)  # this changed

    print "%s : %s" % (inf, weights[inf])
    sum += weights[inf]
print "%s" % sum
```

this yields

```
obj_3 : 0.0389789924094
obj_2 : 0.0012814665648
obj_1 : 0.00185647430241
obj_6 : 0.0103197505417
obj_5 : 0.0416139321457
obj_4 : 0.9
0.994050615964
```

since you already have the fractions in your dictionary, you'd just need to multiply the rest of the numbers by 0.1 (1 - 0.9)?
Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: `set_weight` isn't a percentage. I can't just multiply it with its inverted value. Try it with different values like `0.1` and you'll see the resulted total sum is way off. Thanks though.